# stringByReplacingCharactersInRange does not work?

Tags: ios, string, swift, replace

I am attempting to replace a character with another one. For some reason stringByReplacingCharactersInRange does not work. I have not found a simple explanation on how to resolve this issue.

```
var binaryColor: String = "000"
(binaryColor as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 1), withString: "1")
println("This is binaryColor0: \(binaryColor)")
```

The result is 000 and not 100.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You have to assign `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` to a variable. You're throwing the result away.

Comment: Because strings are immutable, the method only returns a string where some chars have been replaced - the original string remains the same.

Comment: It's always perfectly OK to throw away a value returned from a function, but that doesn't mean you *want* to. I wonder if it's possible for compilers to figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to cast it to NSString to use stringByReplacingCharactersInRange you just need to change the way you create your string range as follow:

update: **Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

```
let binaryColor = "000"
let resultString = binaryColor.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(
    Range(start: binaryColor.startIndex, end: binaryColor.startIndex.advancedBy(1)),
    withString: "1")
```

Or simply

```
let resultString2 = binaryColor.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(
    binaryColor.startIndex..<binaryColor.startIndex.advancedBy(1),
    withString: "1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the variable:

```
var binaryColor: String = "000"
binaryColor = (binaryColor as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, 1), withString: "1")
println("This is binaryColor0: \(binaryColor)")
```